# type vs opaque directives in erlang

Tags: erlang

What is the difference between `-opaque` and `-type`? I saw both in erlang core modules but can't feel the difference.
Is it possible to use `-export_type` for both of them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
%% module1.erl
-export_type([my_tup1/0, my_tup2/0]).
-type my_tup1() :: {any(), any()}.
-opaque my_tup2() :: {any(), any()}.

%% module2.erl
-spec foo1(module1:my_tup1()) -> ok.
foo1({_, _}) -> ok. %% fine

-spec foo2(module1:my_tup2()) -> ok.
foo2({_, _}) -> ok. 
%% Dialyzer warning, because you are looking at 
%% the internal structure of a my_tup2() term.
%% If you defined the same function in the module module1, it wouldn't give a warning.

foo2(_) -> ok. %% no warning again.
```

Yes, you can export both, and if you don't export them, there is no difference.

Comment: Actually there is no meaning in declaring a type as opaque if you don't export it.

Comment: @aronisstav That's just what I said: if you don't export it, they are the same.

Comment: A `-type` declaration is still useful even if you don't export it. An `-opaque` is completely meaningless.

Comment: @aronisstav No. Unexported `-opaque` still defines a type which can be used in the specs in the module.

Comment: I was thinking more about semantical meaning, but now that I think better about it, even then it could have some use.